# Adding category constraints to knapsack algorithm

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

I am attempting to implement the knapsack algorithm to play fantasy basketball. I have written a tradition 0/1 knapsack solver that takes in pairs of values and weights (prices) for each player and outputs the most valuable combo of players whose combined salaries is less than the salary cap.

However, the fantasy competition enforces that you must make up your 8 player lineup based on the positions the players play--ie your lineup must consist of 1 point guard, 1 shooting guard, 1 small forward, 1 power forward, 1 center, 1 shooting guard or point guard, 1 small forward or power forward, and 1 player of any position.

I am looking for advice on how I can extend the traditional dynamic programming knapsack algorithm to include these constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Add another dimension to your array, marking which position in the lineup you've filled.

Answer (score 0):

As Sorin said, you need another state in your DP to keep tracking the filled positions.

Use a bitmask for the third state of your DP, where the *ith* bit indicates whether or not the *ith* role is already taken. For example, 255 = (11111111), which means that every possible role is taken.

This is viable because the number of roles is only eight. Plus, you only need one player per role. Therefore, the third state requires a relatively small array (2^8 = 256). Theoretically, you can use larger bases instead of using a binary one. Generally, your third state would require a *b^r* sized array, where *b = players per role + 1* and *r = roles*, but the memory usage can be huge.